# Code Review Assistant tool(Devart) is not opening/working

Tags: visual-studio-2019, review, devart

after installing when I try to open review assistant board in getting below error.

**command "View.ReviewAssistant.ShowReviewAssistantBoard" is not valid.**

steps tried:

1. Reinstalled visual studio
2. reinstalled review assistant

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Install Review Assistant - Open Visual Studio - EXTENSIONS - Manage Extensions - Click Link Devart Review disabled - restart Visual Studio.